# Why would I get IndexError: list index out of range. When the list index could not be out of range?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I've been building a dice game, and when I got to the part where I assign images to each Tkinter label so that the dice display, I started getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1486, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Logan/Desktop/Dice/dicelab2.py", line 56, in rollDice
    self.dice[i].roll()
  File "C:/Users/Logan/Desktop/Dice/dicelab2.py", line 35, in roll
    self.display.config(image=Photolist[self.value-1])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Now the list has 6 entries in it, and I am calling it from self. value. Self.value is supposed to be a random integer between 1 and 6. Before I call it I subtract 1 so that it should be within the index of Photolist. What else could be causing this error?
Here's my code:

```
import Tkinter
import random
Photolist=[]

class Die:

    def __init__(self,frame):        
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        print self.value
        photo1=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
        photo2=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="2.gif")
        photo3=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="3.gif")
        photo4=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="4.gif")
        photo5=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="5.gif")
        photo6=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="6.gif")

        Photolist=[photo1,photo2,photo3,photo4,photo5,photo6]

        self.display = Tkinter.Label(frame,
          image=Photolist[self.value-1],
          font=('Courier New',30),
          relief='ridge',
          borderwidth=5,
          bg='white')
        self.display.pack(side='left')

    def roll(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        print self.value
        self.display.config(image=Photolist[self.value-1])

class DiceRoller:
    def __init__(self):
        gameWin = Tkinter.Tk()
        gameWin.title('Dice Roller')
        diceFrame = Tkinter.Frame(gameWin)
        self.dice = [ ]
        for i in range(5):
            self.dice.append(Die(diceFrame))

        rollBtn = Tkinter.Button(gameWin,
          text='Roll Again',
          command=self.rollDice,
          font=('Courier New',30)) 
        diceFrame.pack()
        rollBtn.pack(side='bottom')
        gameWin.mainloop()

    def rollDice(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.dice[i].roll()


dice = DiceRoller()
dice
```

Comment: +1 for posting the entire traceback.  Too many people do not.

Comment: Have you tried examining the actual values to see if your assumptions are correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
import Tkinter
import random
# PhotoList = [] you are accessing this

class Die(object):
    def __init__(self,frame):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        print self.value
        photo1=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="1.gif")
        photo2=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="2.gif")
        photo3=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="3.gif")
        photo4=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="4.gif")
        photo5=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="5.gif")
        photo6=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="6.gif")
        # make it an attribute 
        self.Photolist=[photo1,photo2,photo3,photo4,photo5,photo6] 

        self.display = Tkinter.Label(frame,
          image=self.Photolist[self.value-1],
          font=('Courier New',30),
          relief='ridge',
          borderwidth=5,
          bg='white')
        self.display.pack(side='left')

    def roll(self):
        self.value = random.randint(1,6)
        print self.value
        self.display.config(image=self.Photolist[self.value-1])
```

In your code you had `Photolist = []` so you were trying to access that empty list not the one inside your class, I changed it to be an attribute so you should have no problems now

Comment: Holy Hell! How did I miss that?? Thank you!

Comment: no worries, randint is the exception more than the norm so it is an easy mistake to make, usually the upper bound of a range is not inclusive.

Comment: I tried your suggestion of changing the bounds to 'random.randint(1,5)' but I'm still getting the same error.